# Partitioning a set of points in 2D plane

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, partitioning

The problem statement is - 
"You are given a set of N points, where N is even and N <= 1000. You have to find the number of pairs of points, such that if you draw a line through that pair, each side of the line will contains equal number of points(N/2-1)."
I can't figure out, how to solve this problem in O(n^2) or less time?
Here is my brute-force solution-

```
class Point{
public:
   int x, y;
   Point(){x = y = 0;}
   void make_point(int X, int Y){ x = X; y = Y; }
   int Point:: orientation (Point &p0, Point &p1){
     Point p2 = *this;
     Point a = p1 - p0;
     Point b = p2 - p0;
     int area = (a.x * b.y) - (b.x * a.y);
     if (area > 0)return 1;
     if (area < 0)return -1;
     return 0;
   }
};
int main() {
  Point p[4];
  p[0].make_point(0, 0);
  p[1].make_point(0, 1);
  p[2].make_point(1, 1);
  p[3].make_point(1, 0);
  int sz = sizeof(p) / sizeof(p[0]);
  int ans = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++){
    for (int j = i+1; j < sz; j++){
        int leftCnt = 0, rightCnt = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < sz; k++){
            if (k == i || k == j)continue;
            if (p[k].orientation(p[i], p[j]) == 1)leftCnt++;
            if (p[k].orientation(p[i], p[j]) == -1)rightCnt++;
        }
        if (leftCnt == rightCnt && leftCnt == (sz/2-1))ans++;
    }
  }
  cout << ans << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to optimize the solution?

Comment: It is preferred if you will show you effort in trying to solve the problem yourself - at least show us that you tried the brute-force solution of O(n^3) - then you can ask how it can be improved...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've added my brute force approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a simple way do do this in O(n^2 log n) time.

```
for each point O in the set
   for each point A /= O
      calculate the slope of the ray OA 
   sort the points by the slope (this is the n log n limiting step) 
   for each point A /= O
      determine how many points are at either side of the line OA (this is an O(1) job)
```

Perhaps the sorting time could be cut down because a sorted array of slopes would become nearly sorted (only requiring O(n) time to fully sort) when transforming polar co-ordinates to another origin, but I can't prove this at the moment.

Comment: Notice that sort the slope will not do it. move ever - you only want to get the kth element in the slope array which can be done in O(n). consider the follow - 5 point as pentagon and six point in the middle - this case will fail the slope sorting as each of the point of the pentagon answer the constrain with the middle point

Comment: @DavidWinder I don't understand your example. Yes, each point of the pentagon will answer the constraint. The algorithm will find them all as it should. What is your alternative?

Comment: So maybe I misunderstood your algorithm: what exactly you mean by `determine how many points are at either side of the line OA (this is an O(1) job)`? How can you do that given sorted slope array in O(1)?

Comment: I see I didn't explain it well. Visualise the inner loop of the algo as a rotating circle diameter. It divides the circle in two halfs, say red and blue. There are some points on the circle. Initially you know how many of the points are of either colour. Then as the diameter rotates, you know which point it will hit next *with either of its ends* because the points are sorted. Repaint it the opposite colour. Each time there's equal number of red and blue points, you have found one element of the answer. The loop ends when the diameter rotates 180°. O(N) to go past all N points, O(1) per point.

Comment: Thanks! I've implemented this algo. It is working for me and efficient enough.