# Problem related to points on a plane and some technical errors [C++]

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, geometry

**Statement of the problem:** Given n points on a plane (n is even). Find the number of pair of points such that there is an equal number of points on both sides of the line passing through them.

I'm trying by brute-force (~O(n^3)), any suggestion on improving the solution is greatly appreciated. I have also found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52918277/13379374) for the same problem but cannot implement it.

---

**Main Technical problem:** I have marked the part that causes the error with `// HERE`. To be more precise, the errors are:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'sign'
                if(sign(A, B, M) == 1) right++;
```

```
error: no matching function for call to 'sign'
                if(sign(A, B, M) == -1) left++;
```

I think my mistake is probably with `&` thing when defining `A`, `B` and `C`. How can I fix it?

---

**My Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// check which side of the line AB does the point M lie on
int sign(float A[2], float B[2], float M[2]) {
  float det = (A[0] - M[0]) * (B[1] - M[1]) - (B[0] - M[0]) * (A[1] - M[1]);
  if(det > 0) return 1;
  if(det < 0) return -1;
  else return 0;
}

int main() {
    int n, res = 0;
    cin >> n;
    float points[n][2]; // array of points

    // enter points via coordiantes
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        cin >> points[i][j];
        }      
    }
    
    // brute force :(
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int left = 0, right = 0;
        float &A = *points[i];
        for(int j = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if(j == i) continue;
            float &B = *points[j];
            for(int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                if(k == j || k == i) continue;
                float &M = *points[k];
                if(sign(A, B, M) == 1) right++; // HERE
                if(sign(A, B, M) == -1) left++; // HERE
            }
        }
        if(left == right) res++;
    }
  cout << res << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You want a `std::vector<std::array<float,2>> points(n);` in 1st place.

Comment: `float points[n][2];` is a VLA and is not compliant with C++ standard, do as @πάνταῥεῖ suggested.

Comment: `A`, `B` and `C` are references to single `float` values. The `sign` function expects three *pointers* to `float` as arguments. What you want (I guess) is e.g. `float* A = points[i]; (using your current VLA's).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks that tackles the technical part of the problem. However, inputting 4 points (2,1), (2,2), (4,1), (4,3), output is 32767... I don't know what else is wrong with it...

Comment: You need to initialise `res` to 0.

Comment: Uninitialized local variables really *are* uninitialized. They will have an *indeterminate* value, and using an indeterminate value in any way leads to *undefined behavior* in C++.

Comment: @MikeVine Oh, how did I forget that? Thank you.

Comment: This is a common result when a huge pile of C++ code gets written first, and only then an attempt is made to compile, run it, and see if it works. A bunch of problems, hard to isolate and tackle individually. Professional C++ developers don't write code this way. They write a few lines at a time, compile them, test them, see if they work, and only then proceed and write a few more lines of code. It might be easier for you to start from the beginning, and make progress one little step at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need to brute force it, at least `n^2logn` should be better than n^3. I won't write out the code in c++, but I'll explain the algo:

1. Think of each point as the centre of a hub, connected to all the other points by lines. Then each pair of points with that centre makes a certain angle with the x-axis, which you can simply use arctan(deltay/deltax) to find.
2. For each centre, you can then sort (`nlogn`) the angles, and it is easy to know in `O(1)` what the median angle is for that set of angles, and thus the pairs to add to the list. It's a corner case that there might be several co-linear pairs, so don't forget that.
3. So if you do that for n points, sorting nlogn times, you get the solution in `n^2logn`

Comment: Thank you for the algorithm suggestion. I'm now trying to implement it. And I'm having a dilemma: what shall I take as a slope when the line is vertical so that it would not disturb while sorting? I'm going to take max_int, is it ok?

Comment: Yeah that would seem to work, I guess for correctness you still need to check for it separately. I guess if you wanted to you could make your own class that is a [bool + float] but it's a bit overkill.